# For Each In enumeration for custom data set classes

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, enumeration

I have a pretty standard implementation of a circular, two-way linked list. For arrays I'd generally use `for each in` to go through each element without need to worry.

The problem is with my custom Linked List which cannot be looked through with simple call. I'd guess, if there is a Proxy class in AS3 there are high chances the Adobe team came up with an idea to implement, I don't know... Enumerable class or something? Nevertheless my search turned out nil.

Is there a way to make `For Each In` work with a custom class in Flash? Not to **go through all of the object's properties** but **go through the whole data set represented by this class**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read [this post](http://tim-davydik.blogspot.com/2011/07/exploring-proxy-class.html) about [Proxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html) class in my blog. You can find examples of implementing "for each" logic.

Comment: Awesome! I have seen Proxy used before for properties only, and read the documentation some time ago, and so I was pretty sure there was no functionality like that in it; turns out I was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct, check out the [`Proxy` class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html).

Specifically the `nextName`, `nextNameIndex`, and `nextValue` methods will be of interest.

As long as you have easy access your list's elements by index you should be able implement the for...in loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement custom `hasNext()` and `next()` metods, and just iterate through object list

Comment: Also, you can take a look at the Iterator design pattern http://www.as3dp.com/2008/09/04/the-iterator-pattern-flexible-implementation-of-collections/